# Get text color from with Fest framework, within a JTableFixture

Tags: java, jtable, textcolor, fest

I'm inspecting a JTableFixture, with several lines filled with texts. Lines may have different colors.

How can i access the displayed text's color using Fest Framework ?

Here is what i tryed for now

```
JTableFixture eventTable = getTable(); // Get the JTableFixture
JTableCellFixture cell = eventTable.cell(row(0).column(0)); //geting the first cell from the 1st line
cell.editor().getColorModel()..... //Seems retrieving some color datas...
```